# export excel sheet using phpexcel to set rows and columns

Tags: php, excel

i have the database

### roll_no

201261001

201261002

201261003

201261004

201261005

201261006

201261007

201261008

I need to export to excel sheet in 6 rows and 12 columns format

### output

201261001

201261002

201261003

201261004

201261005   201261008

201261006   201261007

The remaining cells should be empty

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: i cant get the output like this. and i dont know how to fix column and row size

Comment: Why not? have you tried writing any code? If so, what code have you written?

Comment: @MarkBaker,Sir i edited the output, how will i do for this output

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will iterate over the resultset from your database query, and write to the appropriate row/column in the spreadsheet. It uses the modulus operator to determine when a column has been filled to 6 rows, and then increments the column and resets the row number ready for the next record.

```
$row = 1;
$column = 'A';
$record = 0;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc) {
    if (($record > 0) && ($record % 6 == 0)) {
        $row = 1;
        $column++;
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$row)->setValue($data['roll_no']);
    $row++;
    $record++;
}
```

Comment: The code that I posted is for PHPExcel (which you did mention in the question).... it isn't going to do anything to help you if all you're doing is generating html markup (which isn't native format Excel anyway)

Comment: Yes, my bad, I was using $row as the counter and also using it for the data read from the database, have modified my example code to fix

Comment: s sir,worked well. but only need to show the 6 row and 12 columns only other cells no need to want

Comment: So what other rows and columns is it showing? If it's showing more than 12 columns, then limit your SQL query to 72 entries

Comment: I need the excel sheet only 68 entries are inserted. Using this code i can insert 56 entries from one table.remaining cells inserted from another table values. Is this possible sir..I tried many

Comment: Then you'll need to read the data from the other table, and use a similar method to populate the cells (but without initialising $row, $column and $record the second time)

Comment: thank u sir, ur suggestion worked well. u r genius. the second table remaining values populates in the another sheet.how will i do?

Comment: Create a new sheet (it will automatically be set as the current active sheet), re-initialise $row, $column and $record for that new sheet; then iterate as previously

Comment: output displayed in snake direction sir.. if this is possible in phpexcel sheet please reply.example output shown above